# Ionic function not running from inside of alert

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3, ionic-view

I have a delete function that is working on browsers but when I do `ionic upload` and try it on my phone is just does not even run it

```
showConfirm(index) {
let confirm = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: 'Delete Lay Minister',
  message: 'Are you sure you want to delete this lay minister?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Disagree',
      handler: () => {
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Agree',
      handler: () => {
        this.doDelete(index);
      }
    }
  ]
});
confirm.present();
}
```

This is the delete function that is not running at all but the alert will run

```
doDelete(index){
    let id = this.layMinisters[index].id;
    this.layMinisterProvider.deleteLayMinister(id).subscribe(
      res => {
        this.presentToast();
        this.layMinisters.splice(index, 1);
     }
    );
}
```

**EDIT::**

Lay Minister Provider

```
deleteLayMinister(id): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.delete(
      this.api.url() + '/faith-leader/' + 'lay-minister/' + id + '/delete',
      {
        headers: new Headers({ "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.access_token })        
      }
    );
}
```

Comment: What does your `LayMinisterProvider` code look like?

Comment: @robbannn The process works on my browser. Which I find strange?? So the provider should not matter that much but I'll post it in